# How to temporary disable bash trace mode before sourcing another script and restore after?

Tags: bash

I need to source some external scripts in bash but I want to avoid displaying the trace output when doing so (set -x).

The current trace status is unknown so I need to restore it after running the source command.

```
# save xtrace status
set +x
source ~/.credentials
# restore xtrace status
```

I cannot use subshells because I would not be able to use the variables defined by the sourced script.

How can I do this in a chean and portable way?

Answer (score 2):

the special variable `$-` contains the current set flags.

```
[[ $- = *x* ]] && old_set_x=1

# disable -x
set +x

# do something

# restore if necessary
((old_set_x)) && set -x
```

Comment: While this seems to be workins it seems that is also triggering a bashate linting error: `E043: arithmetic compound has inconsistent return semantics` on the last line.

Comment: maybe due to the undefined, code is just given as example, could be fixed with `((${old_set_x:-0}))`,  which is the bash version?

Comment: seems you also need in the first line to add: ` || old_set_x=0` , otherwise as soon as one of the section you use that trick had set -x enabled before entering it, all next sections of code you want to use that same trick will have old_set_x set to 1 already, whatever the current setting of xtrace really is